# LocationListener.onLocationChanged not called on Oreo and above

Tags: java, android, location, android-8.0-oreo

I am used below code to get current location:

```
private void getCurrentLocation() {
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Location: " + location.getLatitude() + ", " + location.getLongitude());
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

        }
    };

    String locationProvide = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        return;
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationProvide, 0, 0, locationListener);
    Location lastLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if (lastLocation != null) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Last Location: " + lastLocation.getLatitude() + ", " + lastLocation.getLongitude());
    }
}
```

in AndroidManifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

This works for android below 8 but for 8.1 `onLocationChanged` never called. I finded this [link](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/22439/The-old-Android-LocationListener.html) it says that the LocationListener must be implemented by the class. But it also not help.

Maybe I missed something or Google provide another location method for oreo? I would be grateful for the help. Thanks

Comment: use google api client for more accuracy and recent updates

Comment: use fusedApi for location

Comment: thanks for replies! I'll try it